# delphi and ICS [HTTP.Cli1]

Tags: delphi

So I have I problem with fetching Google search web page.
When I try simple query , for example:

```
http://www.google.ba/search?q=inurl:Stackoverflow&num=100&hl=en&start=0&sa=N
```

In this case it is `inurl:StackOverflow`

And Indy and ICS Http.Cli1 downloads webpage without any problem , but when I try:

```
http://www.google.ba/search?q=inurl:Stackoverflow site:ba&num=100&hl=en&start=0&sa=N
```

In this case query is `inurl:Stackoverflow site:ba` I get bad request , so I looked at address bar and  saw that Google replaces space with %20 , so next I try :

```
idhttp1.get('http://www.google.ba/search?q=inurl:Stackoverflow%20site:ba&num=100&hl=en&start=0&sa=N');
```

I get error with Indy , so I tried ICS

```
Http.Cli1.url('http://www.google.ba/search?q=inurl:Stackoverflow%20site:ba&num=100&hl=en&start=0&sa=N');
Http.cli1.get;
```

And I get 'Service Unavailable' error.
Why is that , when I copy paste link to web browser it opens fine. Why can't I get it with these components.What should I do...

Comment: Which version of Indy are you using?

Comment: I use delphi 7 indy 9.00.10 , but i would prefer to find solution for ICS , when i use indy my program sometimes freezes , with ICS it never happens....

Comment: Indy uses blocking socket operations, by design. If you use it in the context of the main thread, your app will appear frozen while Indy is busy, as the main message loop is not processing new messages. You can drop a TIdAntiFreeze component onto your MainForm, or you can move your Indy logic into a separate worker thread.

Comment: TIdAntiFreeze does great job , thanks for the tip :)